# Meaning of "less set on <something>"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> When I am "less set on" an idea, I will seek help from the teachers here for suggestions.

Does it have the same meaning as this sentence:

> When I have no idea of <something>, I will seek help from the teachers here for suggestions.

Comment: No, the meaning is different: "[to be set on something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-set-on-upon-sth): to be determined to do something:
*She seems set on marrying him*"

Comment: Just think about it for a minute. "The coordinates of the satellite were set for it to meet the sky of NY three times a day." "Being set" is very close in meaning to "being defined". If you are defined, you know what you're gonna do and not gonna let things stop you from doing it. Classic mule. :)

Comment: What does "classic mule" mean?

Comment: @MARamezani i agree with you,"Being set" is very close in meaning to "being defined" we use this often in  mathematics when we want to proof something we have to set the things first i.e define them

Comment: In English (I'm AmEng) you can use 'set' for many different idioms.  One can "set a table", one can "set up a chess game" (put the pieces on the board). MARamezani's example is the same as "set the coordinates" = "set the radio station to 101.5 FM".  That's not the same idiom as OP's "set on an idea".  @CooperKettle's comment is correct.

Comment: *Set on an idea* can also mean 'convinced'. *She's so set on the idea that he's going to marry her that she cannot see that he actually has no interest in her whatsoever!* I actually knew someone like this once. She had a fantasy that this guy was going to be her future husband, "but he didn't know it yet." See [set on the idea that](https://www.google.com/search?q=set+on+the+idea+that).

Comment: Perhaps OP meant "less clear on". Still, surprisingly, nobody asked him "less set THAN WHAT?".  Perhaps the phrasing should be "I'm not so clear on" or "I don't have a solid grasp on" an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

> When I am **less set on** an idea, I will seek help from the teachers for suggestions here.

it means you have knowledge of one or more ideas (or opinions, plans of action, etc.), but you have not decided which one is the one you choose as appropriate in the context given.

When you say:

> When I have **no idea of** {something}, I will seek help from the teachers for suggestions here.

it is literal, you don't have any idea(or opinion, plan of action, etc.), so you will ask for suggestions.

The difference is only what idea or ideas you have going in.

Also the usage of "here" is probably not OK or needed as written. It it difficult to know what "here" is referring to. For example, is "here" the location of the suggestions, teachers, or ??